# Transitions beetwen states in a Finite State Machine Animation in Unity are not occurring

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine, state-machine

I am trying to animate a warrior in Unity. I have created a Finite State Machine as shows the following image. There are three transition parameters: btn_walking, btn_jumping and btn_attacking. When the user holds the key w the btn_walking parameter is set to true, the same occurs to btn_jumping and btn_attacking when the keys j and a are hold, respectivelly.

[image]

However, when the game is launched the warrior keeps on the player_iddle state even the keys w, j and a are pressed down. I am a kid of noob in Unity, probably I am making some mistake.

To the warrior (GameObject player_sprite) is atteched the following script (player.cs):

public class player : MonoBehaviour {

```
private Animator animator;
bool btn_walking = false;
bool btn_jumping = false;
bool btn_attacking = false;
// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

    animator = this.GetComponent<Animator>();

}

// Update is called once per frame
void update() {

    btn_walking = false;
    btn_jumping = false;
    btn_attacking = false;


    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W)){
        btn_walking = true;
        Debug.Log ("clicked on W");
    }

    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.J)){
        btn_jumping = true;
        Debug.Log ("clicked on J");
    }

    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A)){
        btn_attacking = true;
        Debug.Log ("clicked on A");
    }

    animator.SetBool("btn_walking", btn_walking);
    animator.SetBool("btn_jumping", btn_jumping);
    animator.SetBool("btn_attacking", btn_attacking);
}
```

}

I am also atteching my Unity project. Could someone gime a hand? How can I make the warrior change its animation state when the user hold a key?

Thank you!

[link to download at Google drive](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1gFs01ZAzs0JlPKi39gYxUJiGLJLx_1GE)

Comment: Guys, I have figured out my error, update() must be written as Update(). Now the animation works. However, it takes some time to change the states.  When I hold the key w the animation does not change immediately to the walking animation. The same occurs to the other states. Does someone know what I should do?

Comment: I rewrote the if stataments to some like this if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W)){    animator.SetBool("btn_walking", true); }    if(Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.W)){ animator.SetBool("btn_walking", false);} but the animation still take some time to change the state.